# JOIN only if column is NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've two tables as follow:

`tag` table (only tags in english):

```
ID    title
-------------
1     tag_1
2     tag_2
3     tag_3
```

`tag_translation` table:

```
ID    title      locale   tag_id (foreign key)
-----------------------------------------------
1     tag_1_fr   FR        1
2     tag_1_de   DE        1
3     tag_2_es   ES        3
```

How to do a SQL query returning all tags in french, and if no tag found in french, fallback to english?

Example of result (select all tags in french, fallback to english):

```
ID    title
---------------
1     tag_1_fr
2     tag_2
3     tag_3
```

Comment: Is your example wrong? Should the 2nd tag_id in your 2nd set be 1?

Comment: @Goat_CO you're right, fixed.

Comment: So English exists for all tags, but isn't in the translation table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT T.ID
       ,COALESCE(TT.TITLE, T.TITLE) AS TITLE
FROM tag T
LEFT JOIN tag_translation TT
    ON T.ID = TT.tag_id
    AND TT.locale = 'FR';
```

This assumes that tag_id and locale are unique in tag_translation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    CASE
      WHEN TT.locale IS NOT NULL AND TT.locale = 'FR' THEN TT.title
      ELSE t.title
    END title
FROM tag T LEFT JOIN tag_translation TT ON T.ID = TT.tag_id
```

Comment: Be aware that if you there is multiple translation tags there will be duplication, for example on [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/66ed2/1) tag 1 has a translation in english and german, which results in showing 3 rows for tag 1. This could be solved by moving `AND TT.locale = 'FR'` to the join condition [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/66ed2/2)

Comment: @Yuck It will be easier to use `COALESCE` instead of `CASE WHEN`. An you really need to move `TT.locale = 'FR'` to the join condition.

Answer (score 2):

[COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) Should get you what you're after.

```
drop table if exists tag, tag_translation;

create table tag (
id int primary key,
title text
);

insert into tag values (1,'tag_1'), (2, 'tag_2'), (3, 'tag_3');

create table tag_translation (
id      int,
title   text,
locale  text,
tag_id  int references tag (id)
);

insert into tag_translation values
(1,'tag_1_fr', 'FR', 1),
(2,'tag_1_de', 'DE', 1),
(3,'tag_2_es', 'ES', 3);


select id, coalesce(fr.title, en.title) as title
from
(select id, title from tag) as en
left join (select id, title from tag_translation where locale = 'FR') as fr using (id)


 id |  title   
----+----------
  1 | tag_1_fr
  2 | tag_2
  3 | tag_3
```

Comment: Really?. Even though `COALESCE` could be used somehow here, it's certainly **not** gonna solve his problem

Comment: @Lamak I see an answer, that uses `COALESCE` to solve the problem. And it really solves it.

Comment: Funny... I'd have expected postgres to complain that `id` is ambiguous in your last query... else +1.

Comment: @Denis It is a special case of `JOIN ... USING (id)`. It is different from `JOIN ... ON en.id = fr.id` - it leaves only one copy of id in the result query.